# Can you call a computed property from a button click in Vue JS or should you always use a method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code where I can either call a computed property ("edit") or a method ("edit2") from a button click:

```
methods: {
    edit2() {
      console.log(this.editMode);
      this.editMode = !this.editMode;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    edit: function () {
      console.log(this.editMode);
      this.editMode = !this.editMode;
    },
  }
```

and the html:

```
     <b-col md="3" class="my-3" style="float: left;">
        <b-button
          variant="outline-primary"
          class="px-3"
          size="sm"
          style="float: left;"
          @click="edit"
          >Edit</b-button
        >
      </b-col>
```

Calling "edit2" i.e. the method works fine. Calling "edit" the computed property gives the following error:

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"
```

Can I ask why this is? Should one never call a computed property like this?

Thanks

Comment: A computed property should never have side effects. Yes, use a method!

Comment: (What you could do though is have a computed method, i.e. a computed property returning a function)

Answer (score 2):

Always use a method.

The computed property is a calculate variable that your return value is kept in cache. When this variable was change, the computed is reloaded.

If you have doubts, check the official document: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

In official documentation there are many examples that help you understand.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)